# substracting datetime object on date level

Tags: python, datetime

All answers require hour, min, s, etc...
like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

I don't want to create datetime object that contain all hours, minutes, seconds, etc...

Is there a way to add and substract date on higher level(date?)

What I desire:

```
dt = "20210601"
st_date = dt - 30days
print(st_date)
>>> "2021-05-02"
```

What I tried:

```
datetime.strptime("20210601", "%Y%m%d") - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
```

Outputs `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'` which I assume it wants all hours, mins, seconds, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `timedelta` function instead of the `datetime.timedelta` function:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
stdate = datetime.strptime("20210601", "%Y%m%d") - timedelta(days=30)
print(stdate)
```

Output:

```
2021-05-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: Forgot to accept it as an answer. This is perfect, thanks!